# URL hack to execute arbitrary PHP command

Tags: php, url

I have one file index.php(given below). There is another file "other.php" inside folder "myfolder"

```
$a = $_GET['page'];

include('myfolder/' .  $a  .  '.php');
```

The URL is: `localhost/index.php?page=other`

I want to do a hack something like this:

```
localhost/index.php?page=other.php);<MALICIOUS CODE;//
```

(`//` is to comment rest of the line)

Is this possible ?

Comment: Possible, yes. But you don't want to do this as it would be a huge security risk.

Comment: I am trying to learn hacks. But when I do this, the problem is that the whole thing "page=other.php);malicious code;// becomes string and the hack is not succedded

Comment: Read about the difference between strings and PHP code

Comment: Maybe you want to find somewhere else to look for advice on how to compromise other people's security.

Comment: Everything you need to know is at http://www.fbi.gov/about-us/investigate/cyber

Comment: The `);` in the string will not be interpreted by PHP, and therefore will not close the `include` statement

Comment: People..I respect security. I am just trying to learn.

Comment: I did URL encode ; , // etc, the problem is that they are treated as string because there is another string at the end.  '.php'

Comment: @user1834562 You're trying to learn the details of how to exploit security holes, not those of how to prevent them. You need not know the former in order to understand the latter. Asking "how do i exploited hole?" is not likely to make you many friends, especially when you're mixing up code injection and SQL injection and demonstrating no grasp of either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't inject arbitrary PHP code, unless that code gets passed somewhere where it will be evaluated. PHP strings in general are not evaluated as PHP.

There are still potential security vulnerabilities though. The user could load an arbitrary page above `myfolder` by including `../` in the url. They could also run arbitrary code if you have an upload form somewhere that lets them upload PHP files. Since they could upload the code they want to run and then include it from your `index.php`.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to execute arbitrary code from the URL. Instead, try using [directory traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack) and see what interesting code you *can* call.

Also, the `);` and `//` won't be executed. This is different from a SQLi.

The only reason SQLi works in the way you are attempting is because PHP creates the statement and SQL (MySQL, etc) parses the statement. If you created a statement similarly and `eval()` it, it will be essentially the same as SQL reading a statement PHP gives it.

Answer (score 0):

This won't execute the code you supply. It's simply inserted as part of the filename that the `include` function looks for. Variable concatenation doesn't cause the entire PHP line to be re-interpreted.

The only way for user-supplied parameters to be executed by PHP is if the script calls `eval()`, with the parameters included in the argument.

Answer (score 0):

While this wont result in arbitrary code execution as you fear it's still not a good idea.

Imagine if the user did something akin to

```
 localhost/index.php?page=../../dbconfig.ini
```

A better approach is to use a map that will map topic names to files.

```
$pageMap = array("other"=>"other.php", "home"=>"home.php", "about-us"=>"about-us.php");

if (isset($pageMap[$_GET["page"])){
     include $pageMap["page"];
} else {
     // do your 404 code.
}
```